# For loop runs only one time. I need to run up-to 42 times in selenium web-driver

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, nested-loops

I'm trying to fetch the web-table data using for loop. And the table has pagination up-to 42. here my code:

```
driver.get()
#identification and Locators
stack = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[10]/div/ul/li")
quant = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='admin__data-grid-wrap']/table/tbody/tr/td[7]/div")
link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='admin__data-grid-wrap']/table/tbody/tr/td[15]/a")
#Start a procedure
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[2]"):
    for steck,quanty,links in zip(stack,quant,link):
        stuck = steck.text
        quantity = quanty.text
        linkes = links.get_attribute("href")
        if stuck != 'No manage stock':
            word = "Default Stock: "
            stock = stuck.replace(word, '')
            stocks = int(stock)
            quanties = int(float(quantity))
            if stocks < 0:
                print(stocks,quanties,linkes)
                stacks = abs(stocks)
                total = stacks+quanties+1
                print(total)
    i.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    print("Next Page")
```

This code fetches data from the 1st page. after clicking the next page. the 2nd for-loop didn't fetch 2nd-page data from web-table.

Comment: Can you post code that we can reproduce? We have no idea what you are crawling and what the result of the find_elements is

Comment: sure I can give you a code but I can't give the URL. please recheck the question I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your query `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[2]")` only returns one element (the actual button to go to the next page) so I guess you should read the number of page and use it for an outer loop (or at least, you might have to rebind the selection on the HTML element representing the clickable button because it might change when a new page of the table is loaded) :

```
driver.get()

# Read the number of page and store it as an integer
nb_pages = int(driver.find_element_by_id('someId').text)

# Repeat your code (and rebind your selections, notably the one
# on the button to go to the next page) on each page of the table
for page in nb_pages:
    # lines below are adapted from your code, I notably removed you first loop
    stack = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[10]/div/ul/li")
    quant = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='admin__data-grid-wrap']/table/tbody/tr/td[7]/div")
    link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='admin__data-grid-wrap']/table/tbody/tr/td[15]/a")

    # loop removed here (i also splited the string for readability
    # (but it don't change the actual string value)
    i = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"
        "/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[2]")[0]
    for steck, quanty, links in zip(stack, quant, link):
        # your logic ...
        # ...
    # Load the next page:
    i.click()
```

If you can't read the number of page, you may also use a `while` loop and exit it when you can't find a button to load the next page whit something like:

```
while True:
    i = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"
        "/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[2]")
    if not i:
        break
    i = i[0]
    # the rest of your logic
    # ...

    i.click()
```

This is only a guess (as we don't have a sample HTML code of the page / table structure that you are trying to use).

Comment: Thanks for your logic. I almost got the logic to automate my work. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NmHFP1SkkM7tx8YEmxlWLe7qC-nc790D/view?usp=sharing
please see this image. There is no way to read pages.

and while the second loop running `stuck = steck.text` this line through the error **selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document**